# android java url read

Tags: java, android

I use 4.4.2 Android version.
I want to read a url's html code. This url has this code: echo"1";

I'm trying a lot of codes but it isn't work. Pls don't lock this topic. My error: Application stopped.

HttpClient don't work.

android: 4.4.2

program: Android Studio

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

My java code:

```
try {
    URL u = new URL("http://www.google.com");
    BufferedReader br = null;
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(u.openStream()));
    br.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get HTML source code from url in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503574/how-to-get-html-source-code-from-url-in-android)

Comment: it isn't work. It gives error. I solved this problem one year ago but it is giving errors now.

Comment: If it gives some errors, please post the logcat of the error along with the relevant code.

Comment: try use `Okhttp` get method

Comment: Error:(40, 29) error: cannot find symbol class HttpClient
Error:(40, 57) error: cannot find symbol class DefaultHttpClient
Error:(41, 29) error: cannot find symbol class HttpGet