# Android - Load Thumbnail from Website URL using Glide/Picasso

Tags: android, imageview, picasso, android-glide

- I'm trying to load a thumbnail for an article on the web using Glide,
  but it returns an empty field.
- Unlike other examples this URL does not directly link to a PNG/JPG
  etc, rather its a website link from which I require it to load the
  default thumbnail.
- The ImageView has been set & initialised properly.
- I have used Glide & Picasso in separate attempts, but it the
  ImageView is blank.

**Snippet**

```
ivGlide = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivGlide);

String uriLoad = "http://www.recode.net/2016/7/26/12281110/facebook-video-360-degree-camera";

//USING GLIDE
Glide.with(Activity_glidetest.this)
.load(uriLoad) 
.centerCrop()
.into(ivGlide);

    //USING PICASSO
    Picasso.with(Activity_frienddetail.this)
    .load(uriLoad)
    .resize(78, 78)
    .centerCrop()
    .into(ivGlide);
```

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivGlide"
        android:layout_width="78dp"
        android:layout_height="78dp"
        android:src="@drawable/hand"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you give  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in manifest ?

Comment: The url is not an image url, you should pass to Glide/Picasso an image url

Comment: In your example it should be : https://cdn1.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/0LIdoMHrI6QiVjaB00iZCQY17lQ=/800x533/filters:focal(2592x1241:3444x2093):no_upscale()/cdn1.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/50207157/Surround360_1.0.jpg

Comment: @Chol How do I retrieve the image url from the website link?

Comment: Don't know... In the source code page you can find it here <meta property="og:image" content="https://cdn3.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/GpZwP7N6W04JFl2bcA9fDF6gv6o=/0x169:5326x3165/1600x900/cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/50207157/Surround360_1.0.jpg" />

Comment: I think you'll need something to get the html page form the url and then search for the og:image property

Comment: Is there any code for Android that you can share does this? @Chol

Comment: I really don't know, I have never tried, need to find by yourself

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503574/how-to-get-html-source-code-from-url-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide Glide/Picasso a direct link to article image. Try to find this site API, or use some "any website to API" tools, I believe it'll give you article image.

Comment: Is there any code you can share for Android on how to do this?